# отсутп текста от картинки

Tags: html, css, flexbox, padding

Имеются два аналогичных блока с картинками и текстом, чередование которых выстраивается псевдоклассом nth-child(even) - все четные выстраиваются реверсивно. Не могу понять, какой использовать псеводокласс, или же как обратиться к блоку с текстом, четных по порядку, дабы указать ему отступ с другой стороны. Ниже приведен код html и css. Отступ применяется ко всем блокам текста (один и тот же класс). И это логично.
В двух словах - необходимо текст каждого четного блока прижимать к левому краю.
Спасибо!

```css
.middle_content_about_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1300px;
  max-width: 1300px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px 0 100px 0;
}

.middle_content_about_content_text {
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px; 
  color: #000000;
}

.middle_content_about_content_blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.middle_content_about_content_block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0; 
}

.middle_content_about_content_block:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.middle_content_about_content_block_text {
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle_content_about">
                <div class="middle_content_about_content">
                    <div class="middle_content_about_content_blocks">
                        <div class="middle_content_about_content_block">
                            <img src="https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-01/1547367999_1.jpg" alt="">
                            <span class="middle_content_about_content_block_text">
                                Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="middle_content_about_content_block">
                            <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/16.jpg" alt="">
                            <span class="middle_content_about_content_block_text">
                               Есть много вариантов Lorem Ipsum, но большинство из них имеет не всегда приемлемые модификации, например, юмористические вставки или слова, которые даже отдалённо не напоминают латынь. Если вам нужен Lorem Ipsum для серьёзного проекта, вы наверняка не хотите какой-нибудь шутки, скрытой в середине абзаца. Также все другие известные генераторы Lorem Ipsum используют один и тот же текст, который они просто повторяют, пока не достигнут нужный объём. Это делает предлагаемый здесь генератор единственным настоящим Lorem Ipsum генератором. Он использует словарь из более чем 200 латинских слов, а также набор моделей предложений. В результате сгенерированный Lorem Ipsum выглядит правдоподобно, не имеет повторяющихся абзацей или "невозможных" слов.
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не до конца понятно, но предположу что так `.middle_content_about_content_block:nth-child(even):before` :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.middle_content_about_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px 0 100px 0;
}

.middle_content_about_content_text {
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px;
  color: #000000;
}

.middle_content_about_content_blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.middle_content_about_content_block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

.middle_content_about_content_block:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
}

.middle_content_about_content_block:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.middle_content_about_content_block:nth-child(even):before {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

.middle_content_about_content_block_text {
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}

.middle_content_about_content_block:nth-child(even) .middle_content_about_content_block_text {
  padding: 0 50px 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle_content_about">
  <div class="middle_content_about_content">
    <div class="middle_content_about_content_blocks">
      <div class="middle_content_about_content_block">
        <img src="https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-01/1547367999_1.jpg" alt="">
        <span class="middle_content_about_content_block_text">
            Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="middle_content_about_content_block">
        <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/16.jpg" alt="">
        <span class="middle_content_about_content_block_text">
            Есть много вариантов Lorem Ipsum, но большинство из них имеет не всегда приемлемые модификации, например, юмористические вставки или слова, которые даже отдалённо не напоминают латынь. Если вам нужен Lorem Ipsum для серьёзного проекта, вы наверняка не хотите какой-нибудь шутки, скрытой в середине абзаца. Также все другие известные генераторы Lorem Ipsum используют один и тот же текст, который они просто повторяют, пока не достигнут нужный объём. Это делает предлагаемый здесь генератор единственным настоящим Lorem Ipsum генератором. Он использует словарь из более чем 200 латинских слов, а также набор моделей предложений. В результате сгенерированный Lorem Ipsum выглядит правдоподобно, не имеет повторяющихся абзацей или "невозможных" слов.
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое )